My audio isnt working for ubuntu 24.10
I have recently dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 24.10 and my audio worked on my Windows, but switching to this it has been faulty since day one. I have tried deleting and setting up Ubuntu again and it still doesn't work.

I have tried this, deleting pulseaudio and using pipewire instead, switching my dummy output to my speakers, but it still doesn't work.


